# How would I add an extra div to this button?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content2', 2);">A+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content2', -2);">A-</button>
```

I've got an extra section of text that needs to be changed by this button. I've tried this:

```
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content2, middle', 2);">A+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content2, middle', -2);">A-</button>
```

And this

```
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content2', 'middle', 2);">A+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content2', 'middle', -2);">A-</button>
```

Without any luck.

I'm sure it's a simple solution, however I am new, and can not figure this out.

Here's the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeFontSize(element, step) {
var el = document.getElementById(element);
var curFont = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).fontSize, 10);
el.style.fontSize = (curFont + step) + 'px';
}
</script>
```

Comment: `changeFontSize` is a function, can you share that code?

Comment: As quite rightly pointed out by Sinan Samet, you have tagged jQuery. Your code, however, shows no sign of it. Is it available to you?

Comment: Sorry, that was a misclick. I meant to tag Javascript. Thank you by the way, worked like a charm.

Comment: @Jurdun OK no problems, thanks for fixing that. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change `changeFontSize()` to accept an array of element identifiers, rather than one, then loop through each, carrying out your functionality:

```
function changeFontSize(elements, step) {
    var i = 0, el = undefined, curFont = 14;
    for(; i < elements.length; i ++){
        el = document.getElementById(elements[i]);
        if(el != undefined){
            curFont = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).fontSize, 10);
            el.style.fontSize = (curFont + step) + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

And then call your function with an array of `id`s:

```
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize(['content2', 'middle'], 2);">A+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize(['content2', 'middle'], -2);">A-</button>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8t4e491y/)

---

Or use `.querySelectorAll()` which is arguably easier to call on, but has less support and [is slower](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector):

```
function changeFontSize(elements, step) {
    var i = 0, elements = document.querySelectorAll(elements), curFont = 14;
    for(; i < elements.length; i ++){
        if(elements[i] != undefined){
            curFont = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elements[i]).fontSize, 10);
            elements[i].style.fontSize = (curFont + step) + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

```
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('#content2, #middle', 2);">A+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('#content2, #middle', -2);">A-</button>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8t4e491y/2/)

Answer (score 1):

In your code `changeFontSize` calls `document.getElementById` with the first parameter, so `changeFontSize('content2, middle', 2);` may simply run into JS error, because `document.getElementById('content2, middle')` returns `null`.

@George gave an answer that works. Another approach, you could specify a classname as the hook.

```
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content', 2);">A+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize('content', -2);">A-</button>

<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeFontSize(elClass, step) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + elClass);
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var curFont = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(elements[i]).fontSize, 10);
        elements[i].style.fontSize = (curFont + step) + 'px';
    }
}
</script>
```

This may be much more maintainable when you want to add more containers. In such case you just add containers with the hook classname, instead of add more and more parameter to the onclick function call.

Say, you have 10 divs, your HTML would be:

```
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
<div class="content">5</div>
<div class="content">6</div>
<div class="content">7</div>
<div class="content">8</div>
<div class="content">9</div>
<div class="content">10</div>
```

Rather than:

```
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize(['div1', 'div2', 'div3', 'div4', 'div5', 'div6', 'div7', 'div8', 'div9', 'div10'], 2);">A+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="changeFontSize(['div1', 'div2', 'div3', 'div4', 'div5', 'div6', 'div7', 'div8', 'div9', 'div10'], -2);">A-</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to change the font size this way. (I expect jQuery is allowed since it is tagged)

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id='incr'>A+</button>
<button type="button" id='decr'>A-</button>

<div id="content">Resize me</div>
<div id="content">Resize me 2</div>
```

JS:

```
function changeSize(selector, selectorsArr, incr){
 $(document).on("click", selector, function(){
    s = selectorsArr.join(', ');
    var size = $(s).css("font-size");
    $(s).css("font-size", (parseInt(size)+incr)+"px");
 });
}

var selectorsArr = ['#content', '#content2'];
changeSize('#incr', selectorsArr, 2);
changeSize('#decr', selectorsArr, -2);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6bbfmo82/1/)

Comment: Line 2, `this` is `window` actually. Line 4, `this` is the clicked button. Are you sure the asker is going to change the button?

Comment: He can resize, already. Now he wants to control more containers... Please read the question again.

Comment: Ah okay apologies. Editted it